# Which WINAPI function I must use to know if a file is blocked by another process?

Tags: c#

Which WINAPI function can I use to find out if a file has been opened by another process?

I use C# and sometimes get the exception "The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process".

Comment: Do you want to know which other process is using the file or just that it is being used?

Answer (score 2):

Simple try catch should do (catch specific exception though)... if you don't expect the file to be being used then it's ok to just handle the "exceptional" behavior.

In addition, try opening the file with the permissions you need, if you only need to read, open file for reading, another process might just be reading and that don't have to be a problem if you don't try to write it.

Comment: Try to open, and deal with it failing is the only reliable way. Any process of test then open could fail with a race condition where another process opens the file between your process's test and open operations.

Answer (score 0):

How about attempting to open the file exclusively inside a try/catch bloack and then trapping the file used by another process exception to check of the file is busy.